# Ошибка в super(): "Parameter is unfilled"

Tags: python, классы, python-3.6

В самом начале я создал суперкласс "Flower" с полями "type1" и "cost" (я реализовал это при помощи конструктора). Так же в этом классе должен быть метод, который возвращает значения. В данном случае он называется "getinfo".

```
class Flower:
    def __init__(self, type1, cost):
        self.type1 = type1
        self.cost1 = cost

    def getinfo(self):

        return self.type1, self.cost1
```

От этого класса мы наследуем другие классы: "Orchid, Lily, Iris"

```
class Orchid(Flower):
    def __init__(self, color='White'):

        self.color = color
        super().__init__(self)
```

И вот, в строчке с функцией super() мне выдаёт следующую ошибку:

```
line 16, in __init__
    super().__init__(self)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'cost'
```

A если навести курсор на последнюю скобочку, то покажет: "Parameter cost is unfilled"

Остальной код:

```
    def getinfo(self):
        return self.type1, self.cost1, self.color


class Iris(Flower):

    def __init__(self, color='Blue'):
        self.color = color
        super().__init__()

    def getinfo(self):
        return self.type1, self.cost1, self.color


class Lily(Flower):

    def __init__(self, color):
        self.color = color
        super().__init__(self)

    def getinfo(self):
        return self.type1, self.cost1, self.color


orchid = Orchid()

iris = Iris()

print(orchid.color, orchid.type1, orchid.cost1)
```

Хотелось бы понять как работает `super()` и что нужно делать, чтобы прога заработала.

Answer (score 3):

Функция `super()` позволяет обратиться к родительскому классу.
Поэтому инструкция `super().__init__()` вызывает конструктор класса `Flower`.

Метод `__init__` класса `Flower` принимает 2 аргумента (`type1` и `cost`).
Вы их не передали, поэтому получили ошибку.

Для того, чтобы избежать её, Вам следует дополнительно передавать эти аргументы и в новый конструктор, и в конструктор, вызываемый через функцию `super`.
Также замечу, что не следует передавать `self` в конструктор.

***Пример:***

```py
class Flower:
    def __init__(self, type1, cost):
        self.type1 = type1
        self.cost1 = cost

    def get_info(self):
        return self.type1, self.cost1


class Orchid(Flower):
    def __init__(self, type1, cost1, color='White'):
        super().__init__(type1, cost1)
        self.color = color


flower_1 = Orchid('Some type', 'Some cost')
```